# Can I change the version of Lucene that Elasticsearch uses?

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, lucene

I found out that Elasticsearch currently uses Lucene 4.10 under the hood and I also read that Lucene 5 introduced a lot of improvements.
So can I make Elasticsearch to use Lucene 5 instead of 4.10?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Elastic search already uses lucene 5.1.0 in master branch but I don't recommend you to use it in production.

Comment: Master branch is used primary by developers. Releases are in different branches 1.5, 1.4... for example.

Comment: update for 2016: ElasticSearch 2.3.x uses Lucene 5.5 under the hood